# Magento 2 | Product Details API rest/V1/products/:SKU, getting multiple datatype in response

Tags: product, api, magento-2.1.2

Magento 2 | Product Details API `rest/V1/products/:SKU`, getting multiple data types in response so when I am parsing using retro-fit library getting error.

Please suggest what best way to sort it out with a retro-fit library.

Response:

```
"custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "description",
      "value": "<p>Product Features:</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>100% cotton</li>\r\n<li>Interlock jersey</li>\r\n</ul>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "short_description",
      "value": "<p><span>100% cotton, interlock jersey zip up hoodie with hand palm print at chest and Body Glove print on right sleeve.</span></p>"
    },
    
    {
      "attribute_code": "category_ids",
      "value": [
        "3",
        "128"
      ]
    },
```

In response `category_ids` value in the array and other attribute value in the string.